# Shutdown cause -62

Tags: error, logs, reboot

As it says in the topic.

My machine spontaneously rebooted this morning and all the logs have to show is: Shutdown Cause: -62

Only searches only lead to incomplete or deprecated (pre-OSX) lists of error codes.

Hopefully there are people with more inside info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **-62**
>   Watchdog timer detected unresponsive application, restarting the system.
>   Troubleshoot for stuck application, startup item and any loading preferences.

<sup>Source: [Shutdown Causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/)</sup>

Comment: Interesting... Could you comment where you found this information or how I could have retrieved it myself?